# How to hide and show item by item title in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, error-handling

### **I want this** **output:**

if I **click the "A" alphabet header** then "A" alphabet **data only hide**

if I **click the "A" alphabet header** then the "A" alphabet **data only show**

if I **click the "B" alphabet header** then the "B" alphabet **data only hide**

if I **click the "B" alphabet header** then the "B" alphabet **data only show**

### demo:https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cgZd.jpg

### **but I try to do it's working like this:**

if I click the **"A" alphabet header** then **all data is hidden**

if I click the **"A" alphabet header** then **all data is shown**

if I click the **"B" alphabet header** then **all data is shown**

if I click the **"B" alphabet header** then **all data is hidden**

#### demo :https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9urC.jpg

## Code

Main.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import StickyHeaderFlatlist from 'react-native-sticky-header-flatlist';
import { nameData } from './dummydata';

const App = () => {
  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState(true);

  const renderheader = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <>
        {item.title == 'A' ? (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShouldShow(!shouldShow)}>
            <Text style={style.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : null}
             

        {item.title == 'B' ? (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShouldShow(!shouldShow)}>
            <Text style={style.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : null}
      </>
    );
  };
  const renderitem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <>
          {shouldShow ? (
            <View
              style={{
                padding: 10,
                height: 80,
                //borderWidth: 0.5,
                //borderColor: '#000',
                //backgroundColor: '#000',
                marginTop: 10,
              }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: item.img }}
                  style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 30 }}
                />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    marginTop: 0,
                    marginLeft: 10,
                  }}>
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  marginLeft: 60,
                  marginTop: -20,
                  fontSize: 14,
                }}>
                {item.contact}
              </Text>
            </View>
          ) : null}
        </>
      </>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <>
        <Text
          style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 30,
            padding: 10,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }}>
          contact List
        </Text>
        <StickyHeaderFlatlist
          data={nameData}
          keyExtractor={(_, i) => i + ''}
          childrenKey={'contactList'}
          renderHeader={renderheader}
          renderItem={renderitem}
        />
      </>
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```

dummydata.js

```
export const nameData = [
  {
    title: 'A',
    contactList: [
      {
        name: 'Aacgman',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aadesh',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aadi',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aadidev',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aadijay',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aadimoolan',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aadipat',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aadit',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Aaditeya',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    title: 'B',
    contactList: [
      {
        name: 'Baalaark',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Baalan',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Baalakrishan',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Baanbhatt',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Baanke Bihaari',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
      {
        name: 'Baasim',
        contact: 2902912712,
        img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4oOTHA8YZSX72pio8djNOBHxnOP5pFdUC6A&usqp=CAU',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I'm also able to use this [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accordion-collapse-react-native) but I don't know how to use this in my code

if you able to apply any option in my code please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the `shouldShow` variable as an array and add/remove the title shown/hidden:

```
const App = () => {
  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState([]);

  const handleShow = (title) => {
    if (shouldShow.includes(title)) {
      // Hide title
      const updatedShouldShow = [...shouldShow].filter((t) => t !== title);
      setShouldShow(updatedShouldShow);
    } else {
      // Show title
      setShouldShow([...shouldShow, title]);
    }
  };

  const renderheader = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleShow(item.title)}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
    );
  };

  const renderitem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <>
        {item.name[0] !== "" &&
          shouldShow.includes(item.name[0].toUpperCase()) && (
            <View
              style={{
                padding: 10,
                height: 80,
                marginTop: 10
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: item.img }}
                  style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 30 }}
                />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 20,
                    marginTop: 0,
                    marginLeft: 10
                  }}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  marginLeft: 60,
                  marginTop: -20,
                  fontSize: 14
                }}
              >
                {item.contact}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <>
        <Text
          style={{
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: 30,
            padding: 10,
            fontWeight: "bold"
          }}
        >
          contact List
        </Text>
        <StickyHeaderFlatlist
          data={nameData}
          keyExtractor={(_, i) => i + ""}
          childrenKey={"contactList"}
          renderHeader={renderheader}
          renderItem={renderitem}
        />
      </>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dark-monad-gmj5v6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to playground.

Comment: it's not working see here output https://imgur.com/a/89qCyUA

Comment: @GattuPatel this is the correct answer. It might not be working because of a small typo at `handleShow` function, the last line of the else clause `setShouldShow([ ...shouLdShow, title ])`

Comment: yes I also try to do setShouldShow([ ...shouLdShow, title ]) that but it's also not working

Comment: @GattuPatel The problem was that `renderitem` object did not contain the `title` property. You can solve the problem by checking if the name of the contact starts with a given letter. Check the edited answer with a link to a working sandbox.

Comment: default I want to show data how can I do i try to add here  const [shouldShow, setShouldShow] = useState([true]); but it's not working how can I do

Comment: @lpizzinidev please check this when I can hide data then it's space also hide but my output is like that when I hide a data but data space is not hide How can hide the data space here output https://imgur.com/a/eq31iir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105632/how-to-set-custom-heightforindexpath-in-react-native-larglist please check this question

Answer (score 0):

```
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShouldShow(!shouldShow)}>
            <Text style={style.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : null}
```

you are having problem with useEffect setShouldShow, as in current scenario you are having problem due to this event onPress={() => setShouldShow(!shouldShow)}
as shouldShow some time get set to true and sometime to false... if its true then set to false and false then set to true. due to this you are having issues.

Comment: I don't know how to set please post full code with solution if you don't mind